# Recyclerview very slow to load

Tags: java, android, performance, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view in an Activity where sometimes I show a lot of elements. The problem is that when the number of elements is very high the recycler view needs some seconds to render the elements and it's frustrating. I wonder why.
**My code:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="cct.appload.fragments.FileManagerFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/_order_spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/back"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:elevation="1dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/_msg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/manager_progress_bar"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:progressTint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**My single item:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/_icon"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/_separator"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_folder_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/_titolo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Titolo"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/_menu"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/_dimensione"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="dimensione"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/_icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/_menu"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/_titolo" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/_separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@color/lightGrey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In order to update the elements I simply change the list of them and then I notify that to the recycler view.

Comment: What does "very high" mean? 300 or 3000 or...? What kind of data are you displaying? Just text or also some images? On what kind of device/ emulator did you run your code? And, last not least: please share enough of the code  (as well as the layout for the list row) so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @0X0nosugar I edited the question. I don't know exactly how many items I am displaying, I suppose a few hundreds. The are text and images (as you can see). I am working with my moto g5 plus.

Comment: Are you perhaps using the DiffUtil (or the new ListAdapter, implementing the DiffUtil)? In that case, you should know that adding many items to the recycler adapter may take some time since the DiffUtil has to go through all the items and compare the differences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best solution is not loading all data, just using lazy-loading

Refer [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView)

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with a very small amount of items. I'm using Room Dao. 
The reason why RecycleView ran so slow was the **fact that photos that l used were large in size**. So be careful about that.